# I want to edit my recyclerview data on edit text changes and update in model which I am getting from service in json format

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Main Activity

```
public class UserFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserOptionAdapter.PriceChangeNotifier{

List<UserFormModel> userFormModels = new ArrayList<>();
List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Instruction> instructionList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Ticketinfo> ticketinfoList = new ArrayList<>();
TextView tv_ticket_name,tv_ticket_qty,tv_total_price,event_name;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private UserFormAdapter mAdapter;
private UserTicketInfoAdapter utadapter;
ImageView iv_back;
Button btn_submit_form;
public Dialog dialog;
String event_Name;
String qty;

int size;
JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray();
HashMap<Integer, List<Question>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, UserOptionAdapter.Model> hashMapArrShows = new HashMap<String, UserOptionAdapter.Model>();

@Override
public void onPriceChange(String price, HashMap<String, UserOptionAdapter.Model> selectedTicketMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Total price is " + price, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    hashMapArrShows = selectedTicketMap;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_form);
    initView();
    event_Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("EVENT_NAME");
    if(event_Name.equals("")){
    }else{
        event_name.setText(event_Name.toString());
    }

    iv_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventBookingPageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mAdapter = new UserFormAdapter(this, instructionList);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_instruction);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    utadapter = new UserTicketInfoAdapter(this, ticketinfoList);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_questions);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager qLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(qLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(utadapter);


    UserForm("","");

    btn_submit_form.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            size = hashMap.size();
            Toast.makeText(UserFormActivity.this, "LIST SIZE : " + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                size = hashMapArrShows.size();
                Toast.makeText(UserFormActivity.this, "LIST SIZE : " + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                qty = String.valueOf(hashMapArrShows.get("ticket_id"));


                for (Integer key : UserQuestionAdapter.hashMap.keySet()) {
                    List<Option> list = UserQuestionAdapter.hashMap.get(key);
                    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
                    mainObject.put("qid", list.get(0).getId());

                    JSONArray ticketArray = new JSONArray();

                    for (int a = 0; a < list.size(); a++) {
                        JSONObject mainTicket = new JSONObject();
                        mainTicket.put("question_id", list.get(a).getQuestionId());
                        mainTicket.put("question_type_id", list.get(a).getQuestionTypeId());
                        mainTicket.put("text", list.get(a).getStatus());
                        mainTicket.put("status", list.get(a).getText());

                        ticketArray.put(mainTicket);

                    }
                    mainObject.put("options", ticketArray);
                    mainArray.put(mainObject);

                }



                Log.d("PARSED ARRAT :", String.valueOf(mainArray));
                Toast.makeText(UserFormActivity.this, "VALUE : " + mainArray, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                String msg = e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(UserFormActivity.this, "Error : " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


public void initView(){
    iv_back = findViewById(R.id.iv_back);
    tv_ticket_name = findViewById(R.id.ticket_name);
    tv_ticket_qty = findViewById(R.id.ticket_qty);
    tv_total_price = findViewById(R.id.total_price);
    event_name = findViewById(R.id.tv_event_name);
    btn_submit_form = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_form);
}

public void openDailog (String content , String header) {
    dialog = new Dialog(UserFormActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashloading);
    dialog.show();
}


public void UserForm(String eventId,String bookingid){
    openDailog("", "");
    Retrofit rf = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Api api = rf.create(Api.class);
    Call<List<UserFormModel>> call = api.get_booking_form("2635","303");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserFormModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<UserFormModel>> call, Response<List<UserFormModel>> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(UserFormActivity.this, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Result feeds = response.body().get(0).getResult();
                int status = feeds.getStatus();
                if (status == 200){
                    Toast.makeText(UserFormActivity.this, "RESPONSE : 200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    List<Ticketinfo> ticketinfo = response.body().get(0).getTicketinfo();
                    tv_ticket_name.setText(ticketinfo.get(0).getTicketName().toString());
                    tv_ticket_qty.setText(ticketinfo.get(0).getQty().toString());
                    tv_total_price.setText(ticketinfo.get(0).getTotalPrice().toString());
                    if (response.body().get(0).getInstruction().size() > 0){
                        List<Instruction> instructions = response.body().get(0).getInstruction();
                        instructionList.addAll(instructions);
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    List<Ticketinfo> qtlist = response.body().get(0).getTicketinfo();
                    ticketinfoList.addAll(qtlist);
                    utadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else if(status == 500){
                    Toast.makeText(UserFormActivity.this, "RESPONSE : 500", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<UserFormModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("Failure response : ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}





public class UserOptionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserOptionAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

Context context;
List<Option> optionList ;
PriceChangeNotifier priceChangeNotifier;
public int topPosition;

private RadioButton lastCheckedRB = null;
UserOptionAdapter io;

public UserOptionAdapter(Context context, List<Option> optionList,int topPosition,PriceChangeNotifier priceChangeNotifier) {
    this.context = context;
    this.optionList = optionList;
    this.priceChangeNotifier = priceChangeNotifier;
    this.topPosition = topPosition;

}
@Override
public UserOptionAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate
            (R.layout.option_single_row, null);
    return new UserOptionAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserOptionAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tv_options.setTag(position);
    if (optionList.get(position).getQuestionTypeId().equals("1")){
        holder.radioboxId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.radioOne.setText(optionList.get(position).getText());

    }else if(optionList.get(position).getQuestionTypeId().equals("2")){
        holder.checkboxId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.chkone.setText(optionList.get(position).getText());

    }else if(optionList.get(position).getQuestionTypeId().equals("3")){
        holder.textboxId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_options.setText(optionList.get(position).getText());
    }


    Option currentOption = optionList.get(position);
    Model model = new UserOptionAdapter.Model();
    model.setId(optionList.get(position).getId());
    model.setText(optionList.get(position).getText());
    selectedTicketListData.put(optionList.get(position).getId(), model);
    optionList.set(position, currentOption);

    UserQuestionAdapter.hashMap.put(Integer.valueOf(holder.tv_options.getTag().toString()), optionList);

    holder.rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (lastCheckedRB != null) {
                lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
            }
            //store the clicked radiobutton
            lastCheckedRB = checked_rb;
        }
    });




}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    EditText tv_options;
    CheckBox chkone;
    RadioButton radioOne;
    Button btn;
    RadioGroup rg;
    LinearLayout textboxId,checkboxId,radioboxId;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_options = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_options);
        chkone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkOne);
        radioOne = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioOne);



        textboxId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textboxId);
        checkboxId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxId);
        radioboxId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioboxId);

        rg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);

        tv_options.setTag(topPosition);

        tv_options.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               Option currentOption = optionList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                currentOption.setText(s.toString());

                UserOptionAdapter.Model model = new UserOptionAdapter.Model();
                model.setId(currentOption.getId());
                model.setText(currentOption.getText());

                selectedTicketListData.put(currentOption.getText(), model);


                optionList.set(getAdapterPosition(), currentOption);

                UserQuestionAdapter.hashMap.put(Integer.valueOf(tv_options.getTag().toString()), optionList);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });


    }
}
public interface PriceChangeNotifier {
    void onPriceChange(String price, HashMap<String, UserOptionAdapter.Model> selectedTicketMap);
}

public class Model {
    String id,question_id,question_type_id,text,status;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestion_id() {
        return question_id;
    }

    public void setQuestion_id(String question_id) {
        this.question_id = question_id;
    }

    public String getQuestion_type_id() {
        return question_type_id;
    }

    public void setQuestion_type_id(String question_type_id) {
        this.question_type_id = question_type_id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

public static HashMap<String, Model> selectedTicketListData = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return optionList.size();
}

}
```

Whenever I click on text it hides my other option. I want to fetch UserOptionAdapter.Model in Userform how to call it and send it in json?
I need quick help. Will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this simple example. https://github.com/sukie2/currency-converter-mvvm